# replacement for array module in python in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, python-module

Python has an array module which is quite handy in manipulating and managing arrays of basic values ( chars, bytes etc.) . I'm trying to connect over TCP and parse the message responses, which in python is easier, but I need to do it in Ruby.

Is there a gem or a module that achieves what the array module does in python? 
Here is the array module for reference:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

Answer (score 0):

Not really equivalent, but have a look at `Array#pack` and `String#unpack`. These ruby methods are actually closer to perl.